# Disable `S Finder / Quick Connect` in notification panel

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, samsung-touchwiz

My notification panel has `S Finder / Quick Connect` buttons, I would like to disable them, but I cannot find any option in system settings for that.

There is an option `Recommended apps` in `Notification panel` menu, but it does nothing and occasionally crashes settings.

Galaxy Note 3 with Android 5.0, international variant.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK they cannot be removed without voiding your device's warranty, as they are integrated into TouchWiz and are therefore part of the system.

If you really need to get those buttons out of your notification panel, then you would either have to

1. recompile `SystemUI.apk` to remove the section where the buttons are located, or
2. use a custom ROM that's not TouchWiz-based.

Either way, you'll have to void your warranty by obtaining root access in your device. (And let me tell you, warranty is such a pain on recent Samsung devices, what with the introduction of Samsung KNOX.)

Comment: I was hoping there is some well-hidden option in Settings. Oh well, looks like I will have to live with those buttons until Samsung redesignes Touchwiz again.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked on my rooted Note 4:

1. install "ROM Toolbox Pro" and go to "root filemanager"
2. browse to root->system->build.prop
3. open "build.prop" with text-editor and edit the last three letters of this line: "*ro.product.name=*" (example: "ro.product.name=trlt**exx**" to "ro.product.name=trlt**vzw**")
4. save and restart.